# Codeigniter multi-dimensional array return only the first row

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, recursion

One day I'm on this problem and I cant find the solution.
My goal is to return a list of links from an ID (the father). So I want all his childs.
But in the view, I only have on result (the 1st one...).

I have in my controller :

```
$data['list_link'] = $this->menuManager->list_link();
```

In my Model :

```
function list_link($fatherid=0){
    $r = array();
    $sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE fatherid = ' . $fatherid . ' AND siteid = ' . MY_SITEID_DEFAULT . ' ORDER BY name';
    $query = $this->db->query($sSQL);
    // stock results in array
    $r[] = $query->result_array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        // let's find the childs
        $this->list_link($row->id,$loop);
    }
    return $r;
}
```

If I "for each" the $r here, all looks good.
So,  $data['list_link'] shoud now have all the rows.

In my view :

```
 foreach ($list_link as $link){
   foreach ($link as $row){
      echo $row['name'];
   }
}
```

But, I only have the first links (first childs), not the other one. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm on that problem for days...

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing any values in the recursive calls (though I'm still not sure you'd get what you expect). You'd need to populate `$r` with each function call:

```
$r[] = $this->list_link($row->id,$loop);
```

However, either I missed something or you're overcomplicating things, but I think you could simply return the result array and use it:

```
function list_link($fatherid=0,$loop=0){
    $sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE fatherid = ' . $fatherid . ' AND siteid = ' . MY_SITEID_DEFAULT . ' ORDER BY name';
    $query = $this->db->query($sSQL);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

---

UPDATE

Your latest version still doesn't collect the data from recursive calls, here is the full function, see if it works:

```
function list_link($fatherid=0){
    $r = array();
    $sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE fatherid = ' . $fatherid . ' AND siteid = ' . MY_SITEID_DEFAULT . ' ORDER BY name';
    $query = $this->db->query($sSQL);
    $result = $query->result_array();
    // stock results in array
    $r[$fatherid] = $result;
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        // let's find the children
        $r[$fatherid][$row['id']] = $this->list_link($row['id']);
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Note that I've added `$r[$fatherid][$row['id']]` so the end result should be an array with a branching structure. If you don't want that, just do `$r[]` instead.

Comment: Thx for answering, I have to loop to find the childs. That's why I use recursive. But With new test I just noticed I got all lvl 1 childs. As if recursive was not well sets or "r" doesnt have everything for any reason. Maybe I dont use arrays in the good way ?

Comment: Hmm, even if you do it like I've shown you in that first line of code in my answer? Try `var_dump`ing the results and see what's going on.

Comment: `$r = ...` and `$r[] = ...` are not the same. The first one overwrites the value of $r while the second pushes a value to it. I've updated my answer with a full and optimized example.

Comment: I understand how you manage that. I'll try it tomorrow (it's late here). Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Ok I have all the items I need in those arrays now, it works perfectly. thank you very much for your help. I just need to understand how to get those arrays in the view, but when done I'll put an answer so people will have everything in same subject.

Comment: You're welcome. If you took the nesting approach, you'll probably need to loop each category depth-level in order to show the list with a proper hierarchy. This answer answers the actual problem (multiple recursive array not working), so I'm not sure if you post another answer with the view stuff would actually matter (in fact, I think you might get downvoted).